# How to make a variable from a subshell available in the parent shell

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection, subshell

I've written a quick-and-dirty script to time some reports from a web service:

```
BASE_URL='http://example.com/json/webservice/'
FIRST=1
FINAL=10000

for report_code in $(seq 1 $FINAL); do
  (time -p response=$(curl --write-out %{http_code} --silent -O ${BASE_URL}/${report_code}) ) 2> ${report_code}.time

  echo $response  # <------- this is out of scope!  How do I fix that?
  if [[ $response = '404' ]]; then
    echo "Deleting report # ${report_code}!"
    rm ${report_code}
  else
    echo "${report_code} seems to be good!"
  fi
done
```

I need to wrap the `time` command in a subshell so I can redirect its output, but that makes the value of `$response` unavailable to the parent shell.  How do I get around this problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't bring a variable's value from a subshell to its parent, not without doing some error-prone marshalling and cumbersome communication.

Fortunately, you don't need a subshell here. Redirection only requires [command grouping](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Grouping) with `{ … }`, not a subshell.

```
{ time -p response=$(curl --write-out '%{http_code}' --silent -O "${BASE_URL}/${report_code}"); } 2> "${report_code}.time"
```

(Don't forget [double quotes around variable substitutions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters).)

Comment: its funny that every programming language can do that. i already spent 1h googling with no possible solution in shell. im disapointed.

Comment: @ToKra No. No programming language can do this. (Almost) any programming language can bring a variable's value from a *subroutine or instruction block* to its parent, and that's precisely what I explain in my answer: use command grouping `{ … }` instead of a subshell `( … )`.

Comment: Note that the final statement needs the semicolon included in this answer if it is on the same line as the closing brace. Otherwise you'll get a syntax error.

Answer (score 4):

<sub>Fellow U&L users: Before downvoting my answer for using C-style with `main()` function, please visit this link: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/313561/85039 Using main functions in scripts is a common practice, used by many professionals in the field.</sub>

---

As Gilles pointed out, subshells cannot make variables available outside of their environment. But let's approach this problem from another angle - if you write your script in functions, it's possible to declare variable as `local` and that can be edited.

From bash 4.3's manual, `local` description:

> ...When local is used within a function, it causes the variable name to have a visible scope restricted to that function and its children...

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash

outter()
{
    for i in $(seq 1 3)
    do
        var=$i
    done
}

main()
{
    local var=0
    outter
    echo $var
}
main "$@"
$ ./testscript.sh                                                                                                        
3
```

As you can see after 3 iterations of the looping function, the variable is modified.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect your variable in a `test.txt` and get it in the parent shell.

```
testfn()
{
echo "test" > test.txt # redirect your variable in a test.txt
}

testfn &       # execute your function in the subshell

testresult=$(cat test.txt) # get your variable in the parent shell
printf '%s\n' "$testresult"
```

Comment: A race condition is introduced by the use of the ampersand ("&") here. Other than causing `testfn` to run in a subshell, it also causes `testfn` to run in the background asynchronously. This problem does not manifest here due to `echo`'s speed, but consider changing `echo` to a `curl` command like OP or adding a sleep in front of `echo`. Potential results include "test.txt: No such file or directory" or an empty string.


To resolve, keep the parentheses like OP (e.g., `(testfn)`) or add a `wait` after `testfn &` but before `testresult=[...]`

Answer (score 0):

As of bash 4.3 you can do this with [nameref variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameters.html)

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# outvar is a nameref variable that allows us to set the value of a variable 
# outside our scope
addfoo() {
   local x="$1"
   local -n outvar=$2

   x="foo$x"

   outvar="$x"
}

declare b=“loll”

addfoo "bar" b

echo "$b”
```

This will output `foobar` as the function `addfoo` modifies the `b` variable, even though `b` is outside its scope.

Namerefs are useful for extracting values from a function without using a sub shell `$(addfoo)`.