# Why write an entire bash script in functions?

Tags: bash, shell-script, function

At work, I write bash scripts frequently. My supervisor has suggested that the entire script be broken into functions, similar to the following example:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Configure variables
declare_variables() {
    noun=geese
    count=three
}

# Announce something
i_am_foo() {
    echo "I am foo"
    sleep 0.5
    echo "hear me roar!"
}

# Tell a joke
walk_into_bar() {
    echo "So these ${count} ${noun} walk into a bar..."
}

# Emulate a pendulum clock for a bit
do_baz() {
    for i in {1..6}; do
        expr $i % 2 >/dev/null && echo "tick" || echo "tock"
        sleep 1
    done
}

# Establish run order
main() {
    declare_variables
    i_am_foo
    walk_into_bar
    do_baz
}

main
```

Is there any reason to do this other than "readability", which I think could be equally well established with a few more comments and some line spacing?

Does it make the script run more efficiently (I would actually expect the opposite, if anything), or does it make it easier to modify the code beyond the aforementioned readability potential? Or is it really just a stylistic preference?

Please note that although the script doesn't demonstrate it well, the "run order" of the functions in our actual scripts tends to be very linear -- `walk_into_bar` depends on stuff that `i_am_foo` has done, and `do_baz` acts on stuff set up by `walk_into_bar` -- so being able to arbitrarily swap the run order isn't something we would generally be doing. For example, you wouldn't suddenly want to put `declare_variables` after `walk_into_bar`, that would break things.

An example of how I would write the above script would be:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Configure variables
noun=geese
count=three

# Announce something
echo "I am foo"
sleep 0.5
echo "hear me roar!"

# Tell a joke
echo "So these ${count} ${noun} walk into a bar..."

# Emulate a pendulum clock for a bit
for i in {1..6}; do
    expr $i % 2 >/dev/null && echo "tick" || echo "tock"
    sleep 1
done
```

Comment: I like your boss. In my scripts I also put `main()` at the top and add `main "$@"` at the bottom to call it. That lets you see the high level script logic first thing when you open it.

Comment: I disagree with the notion that readability can "be equally well established with a few more comments and some line spacing." Except maybe for fiction, I wouldn't want to deal with a book that doesn't have a table of contents and descriptive names for each chapter and section. In programming languages, that's the kind of readability that functions can provide, and comment's can't.

Comment: Note that variables declared in functions should be declared `local` - this provides variable **scope** which is incredibly important in any non-trivial script.

Comment: @BoristheSpider But in this example, `declare_variables` function declares global variables for whole script.

Comment: I disagree with your boss. If you have to break down your script into functions, you probably shouldn't write a shell script in the first place. Write a program instead.

Comment: Functions are for processes that are repeated, either within the script or in more than one script.  They also allow uniform methodologies to be put into place.  E.g using a function to write to syslog.  As long as everyone uses the same function, your syslog entries are more consistent.  Single use functions like your example needlessly complicate the script.  In some cases, they introduce issues (variable scoping).

Comment: @el.pescado fair point - didn't notice that. Now that I do it makes me shudder a little; something about declaring variables into a global scope from a function makes me want to run for the hills. And I would agree with your second point - Python is a much better choice than Bash in almost every case where people write Bash.

Comment: @Xalorous: Not necessarily, or perhaps I mean not exclusively.  Another good use of functions (IMHO, anyway) is to make the logic clear.  E.g. a main program that consists of { do_x; do_y; do_z; }, with the details of how x, y, and z are actually done abstracted into the function.

Comment: @el.pescado While you shouldn't write too complicated programs in any shell language, few programs are simple enough that they can't profit from some separation of concerns. You almost always do more than 1 thing in a script, so you might as well put those different parts into separate functions. That said bash is arcane enough that the complexity threshold is rather low I agree. But I do write some reasonably complex scripts in powershell these days and that one's actually quite decent to handle complexity.

Comment: testability, maintainability, refactorability, reusability

Comment: @el.pescado You might "like" https://testssl.sh/

Comment: @Rhymoid a lot of major books don't have TOCs and/or descriptive titles. See Killing Floor, Harry Potter novels, and the Running Man by Stephen King.

Comment: @uoɥʇʎPʎzɐɹC That's why I prefaced that sentence with "Except maybe for fiction,".

Comment: @el.pescado, ...I disagree: Treating "scripting" as something less than real programming (and thus not worth doing right) is part of why scripts *are* so awful in general. It's possible to write robust code in bash -- but it requires knowledge and discipline. Approaching "scripting" as something that requires neither perpetuates the status of scripts as buggy, slow[*], insecure garbage, above and beyond the limitations of POSIX-sh-derived languages.

Comment: @el.pescado, ([*] - Yes, many shells interpreters [exceptions exist, see ksh93] are inherently slow, but that inherent slowness pales next to the performance hits caused by sloppy code that makes no attempts to avoid subshells, leverage string-manipulation builtins rather than calling out to external tools, or otherwise to follow best practices in the field).

Comment: @el.pescado, ...saying that "scripts don't need functions" is an example of perpetuating the problem: If scripts are always poorly defined and structured, as encouraging folks not to use functions in writing them perpetuates, they'll never have any opportunity to leave that ghetto, regardless of improvements in the language, runtime, and supporting toolchain (which very much have happened over the past several years and are in fact continuing to happen).

Comment: I was hoping to see a comparison of bash functions vs multiple single use scripts. `i_am_foo(.sh)`, `chmod +x i_am_foo` called by `main.sh` (or whatever better name your entire example has). This is what I'd have suggested as it lets individual modules evolve into [python] whatever language you can best use to handle the growing complexity.

Comment: @BoristheSpider *Python is a much better choice than Bash ...* disagree, and happy to chat about it—(ba)sh still reigns supreme in the world of process and io coordination, as well as direct manipulations of the file system. C comes next, I believe, in those areas—the number of times i’ve had to use the subprocess module’s not-fun syntax to capture command output leaves me not thrilled. `os` v. `mv` &friends is worse. For a set of pipelines, coordinating processes and utilities, redirections, &c., i prefer bash. But these are things I do regularly. And see Charles Duffy’s points.

Comment: your supervisor might have plan to convert the script into a lib file and call those functions for later use, by including that lib file

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I've started using this same style of bash programming after reading [Kfir Lavi's blog post "Defensive Bash Programming"](https://frippertronics.com/posts/defensive_bash_programming.html). He gives quite a few good reasons, but personally I find these the most important:

- procedures become descriptive: it's much easier to figure out what a particular part of code is supposed to do.  Instead of wall of code, you see "Oh, the `find_log_errors` function reads that log file for errors ". Compare it with finding whole lot of awk/grep/sed lines that use god knows what type of regex in the middle of a lengthy script - you've no idea what's it doing there unless there's comments.
- you can debug functions by enclosing into `set -x` and `set +x`. Once you know the rest of the code works alright , you can use this trick to focus on debugging only that specific function. Sure, you can enclose parts of script, but what if it's a lengthy portion ? It's easier to do something like this:

  ```
     set -x
     parse_process_list
     set +x
  ```
- printing usage with `cat <<- EOF . . . EOF`. I've used it quite a few times to make my code much more professional. In addition, `parse_args()` with `getopts` function is quite convenient. Again, this helps with readability, instead of shoving everything into script as giant wall of text. It's also convenient to reuse these.

And obviously, this is much more readable for someone who knows C or Java, or Vala, but has limited bash experience. As far as efficiency goes, there's not a lot of what you can do - bash itself isn't the most efficient language and people prefer perl and python when it comes to speed and efficiency. However, you can `nice` a function:

```
nice -10 resource_hungry_function
```

Compared to calling nice on each and every line of code, this decreases whole lot of typing AND can be conveniently used when you want only a part of your script to run with lower priority.

Running functions in background, in my opinion, also helps when you want to have whole bunch of statements to run in background.

Some of the examples where I've used this style:

- https://askubuntu.com/a/758339/295286
- https://askubuntu.com/a/788654/295286
- https://github.com/SergKolo/sergrep/blob/master/chgreeterbg.sh

Comment: I am not sure you should take any suggestions from that article very seriously. Granted, it has a few good ideas, but it is clearly not someone used to shell scripting. Not a *single* variable in any of the examples is quoted(!) and it suggests using UPPER CASE variable names which is often a very bad idea since they can conflict with existing env vars. *Your* points in this answer make sense, but the linked article seems to have been written by someone who is just used to other languages and is trying to force their style onto bash.

Comment: @terdon  I went back to the article and re-read it. The only place where author mentions upper case variable naming is in "Immutable Global Variables". If you consider global variables as those that have to be within function's environment, then it makes sense to make them capital.  On side note, bash's manual doesn't state convention for variable case. Even [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/42847/85039)  accepted answer says "usually" and  the only "standard" is by Google, which doesn't represent whole IT industry.

Comment: @terdon on another note, I do agree 100% that variable quoting should have been mentioned in the article, and it has been pointed out in the comments on the blog,too. Also, I wouldn't judge someone using this style of coding, regardless of whether or not they're used to another language. This whole question and answers clearly show there's advantages to it, and person's degree to which they're used to another language is probably irrelevant here.

Comment: Sure, and your answer is great (which is why I upvoted it back when you first posted), I just don't think the link is adding anything useful at all. Based on the code presented there, I have no reason to believe the author is qualified to be giving advice on shell scripting. Fair point about globals though, you're right; I thought he was suggesting that all variables be capitalized.

Comment: @terdon well, the article was posted as part of the "source" material. I could have posted everything as my own opinions, but I just had to give credit that some of the stuff I learned from the article, and that all this came from researching over time. The author's linkedin page shows they have good experience with Linux and IT in general, so I'd guess the article doesn't really show that, but I trust in your experience when it comes to Linux and shell scripting, so you might be right.

Comment: That's an excellent answer but I'd also like to add that variable scope in Bash is funky. For that reason, I prefer to declare my variables inside functions using `local` and calling everything via the `main()` function. This makes things a lot more manageable and you can avoid a potentially messy situation.

Answer (score 75):

*Readability* is one thing. But there is more to *modularisation* than just this. (*Semi-modularisation* is maybe more correct for functions.)

In functions you can keep some variables local, which increases *reliability*, decreasing the chance of things getting messed up.

Another pro of functions is *re-usability*. Once a function is coded, it can be applied multiple times in the script. You can also port it to another script.

Your code now may be linear, but in the future you may enter the realm of *multi-threading*, or *multi-processing* in the Bash world. Once you learn to do things in functions, you will be well equipped for the step into the parallel.

One more point to add. As Etsitpab Nioliv notices in the comment below, it's easy to redirect from functions as a coherent entity. But there's one more aspect of redirections with functions. Namely, the redirections can be set along the function definition. Eg.:

```
f () { echo something; } > log
```

Now no explicit redirections are needed by the function calls.

```
$ f
```

This may spare many repetitions, which again increases reliability and helps keeping things in order.

**See also**

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/483304/181255

Comment: Very good answer although it would be much better if it were broken into functions.

Comment: Maybe add that functions allow you to import that script into another script (by using `source` or `. scriptname.sh`, and use those functions as-if they were in your new script.

Comment: That's already covered in another answer.

Comment: I recognize that, but your answer is the top voted one, and is missing this information. Thought it might make yours more complete.

Comment: I appreciate that. But I'd rather let other people be important as well.

Comment: I faced a case today where I had to redirect some of the output of a script to a file (to sent it via email) instead of echoing. I simply had to do myFunction >> myFile to redirect the output of the desired functions. Pretty convenient. Might be relevant.

Answer (score 40):

In my comment, I mentioned three advantages of functions:

1. They are easier to test and verify correctness.
2. Functions can be easily reused (sourced) in future scripts
3. Your boss likes them.

And, never underestimate the importance of number 3.

I would like to address one more issue:

> ... so being able to arbitrarily swap the run order isn't something we
>   would generally be doing. For example, you wouldn't suddenly want to
>   put `declare_variables` after `walk_into_bar`, that would break things.

To get the benefit of breaking code into functions, one should try to make the functions as independent as possible.  If `walk_into_bar` requires a variable that is not used elsewhere, then that variable should be defined in and made local to `walk_into_bar`.  The process of separating the code into functions and minimizing their inter-dependencies should make the code clearer and simpler.

Ideally, functions should be easy to test individually.  If, because of interactions, they are not easy to test, then that is a sign that they might benefit from refactoring.

Comment: I'd argue that it's sometimes sensible to model and enforce those dependencies, vs refactoring to avoid them (since if there are enough of them, and they're sufficiently hairy, that can just lead to a case where things are no longer modularized into functions at all). A very complicated use case once inspired a framework [to do just that](https://github.com/threatgrid/declarative.bash).

Comment: What needs to be divided into functions should be, but the example takes it too far.  I think the only one that really bugs me is the variable declaration function.  Global variables, especially static ones, should be defined globally in a commented section dedicated to that purpose.  Dynamic variables should be local to the functions that use and modify them.

Comment: @Xalorous I've seen a practices where global variables are  _Initialized_  in a procedure, as an intermediate and quick step before the developing of a procedure that reads their value from an external file... I agree it should be cleaner to separate definition and initialization but seldom you have to bend to undergo to the advantage number 3 `;-)`

Answer (score 18):

While I totally agree with the *reusability*, *readability*, and delicately kissing the bosses but there is one other advantage of functions in [bash](/questions/tagged/bash): *variable scope*.  As [LDP shows](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/localvar.html):

```
#!/bin/bash
# ex62.sh: Global and local variables inside a function.

func ()
{
  local loc_var=23       # Declared as local variable.
  echo                   # Uses the 'local' builtin.
  echo "\"loc_var\" in function = $loc_var"
  global_var=999         # Not declared as local.
                         # Therefore, defaults to global. 
  echo "\"global_var\" in function = $global_var"
}  

func

# Now, to see if local variable "loc_var" exists outside the function.

echo
echo "\"loc_var\" outside function = $loc_var"
                                      # $loc_var outside function = 
                                      # No, $loc_var not visible globally.
echo "\"global_var\" outside function = $global_var"
                                      # $global_var outside function = 999
                                      # $global_var is visible globally.
echo                      

exit 0
#  In contrast to C, a Bash variable declared inside a function
#+ is local ONLY if declared as such.
```

I don't see this very often in real world shell scripts, but it seems like a good idea for more complex scripts.  Reducing [cohesion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_(computer_science)) helps avoid bugs where you're clobbering a variable expected in another part of the code.

Reusability often means creating a common library of functions and `source`ing that library into all of your scripts.  This won't help them run faster, but it will help you write them faster.

Comment: Few people are explicitly using `local`, but I think most people writing scripts broken up into functions still follow the design principle. Usign `local` just makes it harder to introduce bugs.

Comment: `local` makes variables available to function and its children, so it's really nice to have a variable that can be passed down from function A , but unavailable to function B, which may want to have variable with same name but different purpose. So that's good for defining the scope, and as Voo said - less bugs

Answer (score 17):

You break the code into functions for the same reason you would do that for C/C++, python, perl, ruby or whatever programming language code. The deeper reason is abstraction - you encapsulate lower level tasks into higher level primitives (functions) so that you don't need to bother about how things are done. At the same time, the code becomes more readable (and maintainable), and the program logic becomes more clear.

However, looking at your code, I find it quite odd to have a function to declare variables; this really makes me rise an eye brow.

Comment: Underrated answer IMHO. Do you suggest to declare the variables in the `main` function/method, then?

Answer (score 11):

A completely different reason from those already given in other answers: one reason this technique is sometimes used, where the sole non-function-definition statement at top-level is a call to `main`, is to make sure the script does not accidentally do anything nasty if the script is truncated. The script may be truncated if it is piped from process A to process B (the shell), and process A terminates for whatever reason before it has finished writing the whole script. This is especially likely to happen if process A fetches the script from a remote resource. While for security reasons that is not a good idea, it is something that is done, and some scripts have been modified to anticipate the problem.

Comment: Interesting! But I find it troubling that one has to take care of those things in each of the programs. On the other hand, exactly this `main()` pattern is usual in Python where one uses `if __name__ == '__main__': main()` at the end of the file.

Comment: The python idiom has the advantage of letting other scripts `import` the current script without running `main`.  I suppose a similar guard could be put in a bash script.

Comment: @Jake Cobb Yes. I now do that in all new bash scripts. I have a script that contains a core infrastructure of functions used by all new scripts. That script can be sourced or executed. If sourced, its main function is not executed. Detection of source vs execution is via the fact that the BASH_SOURCE contains the name of the executing script. If it's the same as the the core script, the script is being executed. Otherwise, it's being sourced.

Comment: Closely related to this answer, bash uses simple line-based processing when running from a file already on disk.  If the file changes while the script is running, the line counter doesn't change and it'll continue on the wrong line.  Encapsulating everything in functions ensures it's all loaded into memory before running anything, so altering the file doesn't affect it.

Answer (score 8):

Some relevant truisms about programming:

- **Your program will change,** even if your boss insists this is not the case.
- **Only code and input** affect the behavior of the program.
- [**Naming** is difficult.](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html)

Comments start out as a stop-gap for not being able to express your ideas clearly in code*, and get worse (or simply wrong) with change. Therefore, if at all possible, express concepts, structures, reasoning, semantics, flow, error handling and anything else pertinent to the understanding of the code *as code.*

That said, Bash functions have some issues not found in most languages:

- Namespacing is terrible in Bash. For example, forgetting to use the `local` keyword results in polluting the global namespace.
- Using `local foo="$(bar)"` results in [*losing* the exit code of `bar`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#local_varname.3D.24.28command.29).
- There are no named parameters, so you have to keep in mind what `"$@"` means in different contexts.

* I'm sorry if this offends, but after using comments for some years and developing without them** for more years it's pretty clear which is superior.

** Using comments for licensing, API documentation and the like is still necessary.

Comment: I set almost all local variables by declaring them to null at the beginning of the function... `local foo=""` Then setting them using command execution to act on the result... `foo="$(bar)" || { echo "bar() failed"; return 1; }`. This gets us out of the function quickly when a required value cannot be set. The curly braces are necessary to insure that the `return 1` is only executed on failure.

Comment: Just wanted to comment on your bullet points.  If you use 'subshell functions'  (functions delimited by parenthesis and not curly brackets),  you 1) don't have to use local but get the benefits of local, 2) Don't run into the problem of losing the exit code of command substitution in `local foo=$(bar)` as much (because you're not using local) 3) Don't have to worry about accidently polluting or changing global scope 4) are able to pass in 'named parameters' that are 'local' to your function by using the syntax `foo=bar baz=buz my-command`

Comment: A simple non-subshell, exit-status-preserving way to do this exists with bash. E.g. see https://github.com/dylanaraps/pure-bash-bible#capture-the-return-value-of-a-function-without-command-substitution

Answer (score 7):

A process requires a sequence. Most tasks are sequential. It makes no sense to mess with the order.

But the super big thing about programming - which includes scripting - is testing. Testing, testing, testing. What test scripts do you currently have to validate the correctness of your scripts?

Your boss is trying to guide you from being a script kiddy to being a programmer. This is a good direction to go in. People who come after you will like you.

BUT. Always remember your process-oriented roots. If it makes sense to have the functions ordered in the sequence in which they are typically executed, then do that, at least as a first pass.

Later, you will come to see that some of your functions are handling input, others output, others processing, others modelling data, and others manipulating the data, so it may be smart to group similar methods, perhaps even moving them off into separate files.

Later still, you may come to realize you've now written libraries of little helper functions that you use in many of your scripts.

Answer (score 7):

Comments and spacing can *not* get anywhere near the readability that functions can, as I will demonstrate. Without functions, you can't see the forest for the trees - big problems hide among many lines of detail. In other words, people can't simultaneously focus on the fine details and on the big picture. That might not be obvious in a short script; so long as it remains short it may be readable enough. Software gets bigger, though, not smaller, and certainly  it's part of the entire software system of  your company, which is surely very much larger, probably millions of lines.

Consider if I gave you instructions such as this:

```
Place your hands on your desk.
Tense your arm muscles.
Extend your knee and hip joints.
Relax your arms.
Move your arms backwards.
Move your left leg backwards.
Move your right leg backwards.
(continue for 10,000 more lines)
```

By the time you got halfway through, or even 5% through, you would have forgotten what the first several steps were. You couldn't possibly spot most problems, because you couldn't see the forest for the trees.  Compare with functions:

```
stand_up();
walk_to(break_room);
pour(coffee);
walk_to(office);
```

That's certainly much more understandable, no matter how many comments you might put in the line-by-line sequential version.  It also makes it *far* more likely you'll notice that you forgot to **make** the coffee, and probably forgot sit_down() at the end. When your mind is thinking of the details of grep and awk regexes, you can't be thinking big picture - "what if there is no coffee made"?

Functions primarily allow you to see the big picture, and notice that you forgot to make the coffee (or that someone might prefer tea). At another time, in a different frame of mind, you worry about the detailed implementation.

There are also other benefits discussed in other answers, of course. Another benefit not clearly stated in the other answers is that functions provide a guarantee that's important in preventing and fixing bugs. If you discover that some variable $foo in the proper function walk_to() was wrong, you know that you only have to look at the other 6 lines of that function to find everything that could have been affected by that problem, and everything that could have caused it to be wrong.  Without (proper) functions, anything and everything in the whole system might be a cause of $foo being incorrect, and anything and everything might be affected by $foo.  Therefore you can't safely fix $foo without re-examining every single line of the program. If $foo is local to a function, you can guarantee any changes are safe and correct by checking only that function.

Comment: This isn't `bash` syntax. It's a shame though; I don't think there is a way to pass input to functions like that. (i.e. `pour();` < `coffee`). It looks more like `c++` or `php` (I think).

Comment: @tjt263 without the parentheses, it's bash syntax:
pour coffee.
With parens, it's pretty much every other language. :)

Answer (score 6):

### *Time is money*

There are **other good answers** that spread light on the technical reasons to write *modularly* a script, potentially long, developed in a working environment, developed to be used by *a group of persons* and not only for your own use.

I want to **focus** on one expect: in a working environment **"time is money"**. So the absence of bugs and the performances of your code are evaluated together with **readibility**, testability, maintainability, refactorability, **reusability**...

**Writing in *"modules"*** a code will decrease the reading time needed not only by the *coder* itself, but even the time used by the testers or by the boss. Moreover note that the time of a boss is usually paid more then the time of a coder and that your boss will evaluate the quality of your job.

Furthermore writing in **independent *"modules"*** a code (even a bash script) will allow you to  work in *"parallel"* with other component of your team shortening the overall production time and using at best the single's expertise, to review or rewrite a part with no side effect on the others, to recycle the code you have just written *"as is"* for another program/script, to create libraries (or libraries of snippets), to reduce the overall size and the related likelihood of errors, to debug and test thorough each single part... and of course it will organize in logical section your program/script and enhance its readability. All things that will save time and so money. The drawback is that you have to stick to standards and comment your functions (that you have nonetheless to do in a working environment).

To adhere to a **standard** will slow down your work in the beginning but it will speed up the work of all the others (and your too) afterwards. Indeed when the collaboration grows in number of people involved this becomes an unavoidable need.  So, for example, even if I believe that the global variables have to be defined *globally* and not in a function, I can understand a standard that  inizializes them in a function named  `declare_variables()` called always in the first line of the `main()` one...

Last but not least, do not underestimate the possibility in modern source code editors to show or to hide selectively separate routines ([**Code folding**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_folding)). This will keep compact the code and focused the user saving again time.

[image]

<sup>Here above you can see how it is *unfolded* only the `walk_into_bar()` function. Even of the other ones were 1000 lines long each, you could still keep under control all the code in a single page. Note it is folded even the section where you go to declare/initialize the variables.</sup>

Answer (score 5):

Another reason that is often overlooked is bash's syntax parsing:

```
set -eu

echo "this shouldn't run"
{
echo "this shouldn't run either"
```

This script obviously contains a syntax error and bash shouldn't run it at all, right? Wrong.

```
~ $ bash t1.sh
this shouldn't run
t1.sh: line 7: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

If we wrapped the code in a function, this wouldn't happen:

```
set -eu

main() {
  echo "this shouldn't run"
  {
  echo "this shouldn't run either"
}

main
```

```
~ $ bash t1.sh
t1.sh: line 10: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Answer (score 3):

Aside from the reasons given in other answers:

> 9. Psychology: A programmer whose productivity is being measured in lines
>      of code will have an incentive to write unnecessarily verbose code.
>      The more management is focusing on lines of code, the more incentive
>      the programmer has to expand his code with unneeded complexity. This
>      is undesirable since increased complexity can lead to increased cost
>      of maintenance and increased effort required for bug fixing.
>
>    - [WP, Source Lines of Code; Disadvantages, #9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_lines_of_code#Disadvantages)

Comment: It is not so bad answer, as the downvotes say. Note: agc says, also this is a possibility, and yes, it is. He doesn't say it would be the only possibility, and doesn't accuse anybody, only states the facts. Although I think today is nearly unheard a direct "code line" --> "$$" style contract job, on indirect means it is quite common, that yes, the mass of the produced code counts by the leaders/bosses.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons I do it:

Bash reads the script line by line (well, buffered in small chunks behind that) and runs as it reads.

If I'm editing a script while it's running and I hit "save", then as bash reads more of the script it will get garbage.

If I wrap everything in functions and then call `main "$@"` at the end, it forces bash to read the entire script into memory before it starts running anything significant from it.

Comment: Not true. If you edit/change/save a script whilst it is running, you will need to restart the script to get the new version.

Comment: I didn't claim that the script would hot-patch.  Just that bash wouldn't end up reading garbage as it would do if streaming in the script as it runs it.