# How to Group Commands After '&&' or '||' Branch and Not Invoke Subshell Variable Restriction?

Tags: bash, shell-script, error-handling

This script just tries to copy file `foo` to `bar/`, and if it`s unsuccessful, retries 2 more times.

**EDIT:** as it turns out, the reason the second example works and the first does not, is because the use of `(...)` to run a group of commands after the `&&` or `||` branch is considered a subshell and does not affect the outer variable.

**So revised question:** how can I group some commands like the first example, but not use a subshell to do so?

**EDIT 2:** the answer is to replace `( ... )` with `{ ...; }`!

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#

# Be safe
set -euo pipefail

# Init variables
__file="foo"
output_dir="bar"
logfile="test.log"
errorlevel=8
count=0

# Try three times to copy a file
until (( errorlevel == 0 || count == 3 )); do

  cp -Lv --no-preserve=mode \
    "$__file" \
    "$output_dir/" \
    | tee -a "$logfile" \
    && (errorlevel=$?; echo "zero return, $errorlevel") \
    || (errorlevel=$?; echo "non-zero return, $errorlevel")

  echo "errorlevel $errorlevel"

  (( ++count ))

  echo "count $count"

done

unset errorlevel
unset count
```

The problem:

When the copy fails, or is successful, the `||` or `&&` branch catches correctly and sets variable `errorlevel` to `1` or `0`, respectively, as evidenced with the `echo $errorlevel` contained within the branch.

But the very next command, also an echo, returns the initial variable value of `8`! I don't understand why this is happening.

A few notes:

1. I'm using `&&` and `||` explicitly because I have `set -e` to make this script as safe as possible (this is actually a small routine in a 1500-line script). If I don't use `||` to catch a non-zero return, the script exits. Alternatively I could `set +e`, do the copy routine without having to use `&&` and `||` (by catching the errorlevel once), and then `set -e` again, but I'd rather not because it doesn't match the style of the rest of my script.
2. I'm using `set -o pipefail` to pass a non-zero errorlevel down the pipeline so that my `tee -a "$logfile"` doesn't always override my exit `errorlevel`.
3. I'm using `++count` instead of `count++` because the former returns a zero errorlevel, and the latter returns a non-zero errorlevel (and I would have to do an ugly `(( count++ )) || true` because of the `set -e` explained in note #1).

I have worked around it for now by setting the `errorlevel` variable explicitly to `1` or `0`, since I actually don't care what the non-zero `errorlevel` is, but I would still really like to know why the above isn`t working as I expect.

Here's the workaround:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#

set -euo pipefail

__file="foo"
output_dir="bar"
logfile="test.log"

errorlevel=1
count=0
until (( errorlevel == 0 || count == 5 )); do
  cp -Lv --no-preserve=mode \
    "$__file" \
    "$output_dir/" \
    | tee -a "$logfile" \
    && errorlevel=0 \
    || errorlevel=1
  (( ++count ))
  sleep 1
done

unset errorlevel
unset count
```

Any insight is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Possibly related: [How to make a variable from a subshell available in the parent shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/140043/how-to-make-a-variable-from-a-subshell-available-in-the-parent-shell)

Comment: Thanks! That offered a clue as to why the first attempt failed and the second attempt worked. It turns out that when ( ... ) is used, it's treated as a subshell of sorts. I'm going to revise my question to see if anyone know how to group some commands without creating a subshell.

Comment: Have you tried `{ . . . }` *command grouping* - as described in the [accepted answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/140049/65304) ?

Comment: Yes, and I received syntax errors when I did so. Any suggestions on how to replace the '( ... )' with '{ ... }' that would be successful? Error with '{ ... }' was "syntax error near unexpected token 'done'", and error with '{...}' was "errorlevel=0: command not found". Does '{ ... }' only work within functions perhaps?

Comment: Got it! '( ... )' must be replaced with '{ ...; }'! You rock, thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

I'd prefer to use an `if` block:

```
errorlevel=0
if cp -Lv --no-preserve=mode \
    "$__file" \
    "$output_dir/" \
    | tee -a "$logfile"
then
    echo "zero return, $errorlevel"
else
    errorlevel=$?
    echo "non-zero return, $errorlevel"
fi
```

The `if` protects a non-zero exit status from triggering the `-e` exit-on-error action.

(The original problem, of course, is that `( )` creates a subshell, so the variable assignment is never affects the parent shell.)