# count variable not getting incremented

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, variable

I have a scenario where I am running the following code:

```
error_count=0
(cd tmp1 && terraform init -backend=false > /dev/null && terraform validate && echo "Terraform format check passed successfully in -------> xxx" && rm -rf .terraform*) || (echo "Terraform validation failed in xxx" && cd tmp && rm -rf .terraform* && let "error_count=error_count+1")

(cd tmp2 && terraform init -backend=false > /dev/null && terraform validate && echo "Terraform format check passed successfully in -------> yyy" && rm -rf .terraform*) || (echo "Terraform validation failed in yyy" && cd tmp && rm -rf .terraform* && let "error_count=error_count+1")
echo $error_count
if [ "$error_count" -gt 0 ]; then
  echo "terraform check failed"
  exit 1
else
  echo "terraform check passed"
fi
```

What I observe here is even if the condition fails, the `error_count=0` value remains the same. How can I increment the counter on a failing condition?

Comment: Does this answer your question? - [How to make a variable from a subshell available in the parent shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/140043/100397)

Answer (score 2):

As [roaima](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/100397/roaima) commented, the core of your question boils down to the subshell environment (in `(cd ... )`) exiting completely, leaving the `let "error_count=error_count+1"` behind, and not affecting the parent shell's value of error_count.

I would recommend refactoring the code a bit so that you have a reusable function to execute the common functionality and have it return a success or failure code:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
terraform_init_and_validate() (
  if    cd "$1" &&
        terraform init -backend=false > /dev/null &&
        terraform validate
  then
        echo "Terraform format check passed successfully in -------> xxx"
        rm -rf .terraform*
        return 0
  else
        echo "Terraform validation failed in xxx"
        cd tmp && rm -rf .terraform*
        return 1
  fi
)

error_count=0
if ! terraform_init_and_validate tmp1
then
  let "error_count=error_count+1"
fi

if ! terraform_init_and_validate tmp2
then
  let "error_count=error_count+1"
fi

echo $error_count
if [ "$error_count" -gt 0 ]; then
  echo "terraform check failed"
  exit 1
else
  echo "terraform check passed"
fi
```

The terraform_init_and_validate function runs the code in a subshell, maintaining that isolation for the `cd` commands, but returns a true or false value depending on the success or failure of the two terraform commands. The main script then calls that function with the two different parameters and increments error_count only if the function returned an error code.

I would also point out a minor discrepancy (to my eyes): that the "success" branch of your code does a `rm -rf .terraform*` from the initial directory but the "failure" branch does a `cd tmp && rm -rf .terraform*`, which removes files from a *subdirectory* of the initial directory.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs, but if I refactor code like this then if I need to run some pre-steps for let say `tmp2` how do I do that ?
something like this scenario `if executing directory is tmp2 then echo "something"`

Comment: Well, I just saw lots of duplicated code, and along with the idea of separating the `cd` to a subshell, a function sprang to mind.  There's always more than one way to do it. Perhaps before calling `if ! terraform_init_and_validate tmp2` you insert the code there?